# Is LAN with StarCraft 2 definitely not possible?

Tags: starcraft-2

I searched around the web, even in the official SCII com forums, but I could not get an exact answer on this question:

"Is LAN with SCII definitely not possible or is there a way to get the PCs inside the LAN connected even through the Battle.NET without connecting the computers via Internet?"

I heard about work-arounds, where you still use battle net but after connecting to the certain players you let the connection run over the local network.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Judging from your question you want SC2 over LAN without connecting via the Internet.  There is no easy way to do this.  As McKay points out, as long as all computers are connected to the Internet you can use computers which happen to be connected to the same LAN, but make no mistake you will not be leveraging the advantage of said LAN.

Now I said "easy way," because there is a "hard way."  Blizzard does have a LAN client of Starcraft II which is provides for reputable tournaments.  Gaining access to this requires setting yourself up as a business organization and paying a licensing fee. For more information you're going to have to contact Blizzard directly.

That said, for a couple of friends, there is no legal way to leverage your LAN for SC2 games without going through Blizzard.

Comment: I've been looking for information about getting a specific LAN client. Is there any **official** word on that?

Comment: @McKay the official word is all LAN clients are leased at the discretion of blizzard to notable organizations.  This does not constitute a sale and all leases are temporary.

Comment: @McKay blizzard claims that they will release a patch "soon after release" which will allow people to take advantage of being on a LAN.  You'll still need to be able to connect to battle.net though.

Comment: @T M, Can you link an article of blizz stating that?

Answer (score 0):

StarCraft II works fine over a LAN.

It does require an Internet connection, because you have to connect to battle.net, but it does work.

It does have a problem with disconnects, especially when a large number (20+?) connect from one IP address, but LAN games work fine over Battle.NET.

I have held and attended several StarCraft II LAN parties.

Update:
The latency is still the same as non-LAN games, because the actions are still sent to Battle.NET and back, but generally it isn't a big issue.

Comment: So there are no latency/ping problems while playing, because after connecting through BNET the computers are connected directly through LAN and not Internet, right?

Comment: @camino that is incorrect, there will still be latency and ping problems as you still have to connect through the Battle.NET.  That said Battle.NET has good data persistence and tends to make things smooth on its own.

Comment: Also the game will freeze when someone's ping get's too high. When this happens for longer than 60 secs (in total) the player get's kicked. So at least they try to balance things

Comment: This technically is not working over a LAN then, so your answer is misleading.  tzenes has a much more complete answer.

Comment: @StrixVaria I certainly agree with you, let's hope more people upvote my answer to indicate this.

Comment: @tzenes I already changed your answer to "ansered"

Answer (score -3):

Korean entrepreneurs put on Starcraft LAN tournaments and made some money via televised e-sports events, and Blizzard never saw a dime.

Blizzard will never let that happen again thus, no LAN.