# How to play Starcraft II 1v1 on local LAN

Tags: starcraft-2

I'm happy LAN play is available. But, I want to play 1v1 instead of 2vX cooperative. If I have the other player in a party, I'm able to try to start a 1v1 game, and my partner is able to accept, but it immediately says there are too many people in my party for that mode of play.

Is cooperative mode the only way to play with people on a local LAN? If not, how do I play 1v1 with a LAN partner?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is LAN with StarCraft 2 definitely not possible?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5097/is-lan-with-starcraft-2-definitely-not-possible)

Comment: @Paul not at all. I don’t have a problem connecting to battle.net to play and I don’t have a problem playing with other LAN players. What I want to do is specifically play 1v1 head to head.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set up a custom game with 1 v 1 settings:

> 1. Click Custom Games.
> 2. Choose map and press create game.
> 3. Right click on friend in friendlist.
> 4. Press invite to game.

[source](https://eu.battle.net/forums/en/sc2/topic/7714001693)